# Executing logic before save or validation with EF Code-First Models

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm still getting accustomed to EF Code First, having spent years working with the Ruby ORM, ActiveRecord. ActiveRecord used to have all sorts of [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) like before_validation and before_save, where it was possible to modify the object before it would be sent off to the data layer. I am wondering if there is an equivalent technique in EF Code First object modeling.

I know how to set object members at the time of instantiation, of course, (to set default values and so forth) but sometimes you need to intervene at different moments in the object lifecycle.

To use a slightly contrived example, say I have a join table linking Authors and Plays, represented with a corresponding Authoring object:

```
public class Authoring
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int Position { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public virtual Play Play { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

where Position represents a zero-indexed ordering of the Authors associated to a given Play. (You might have a single "South Pacific" Play with two authors: a "Rodgers" author with a Position 0 and a "Hammerstein" author with a Position 1.)

Let's say I wanted to create a method that, before saving away an Authoring record, it checked to see if there were any existing authors for the Play to which it was associated. If no, it set the Position to 0. If yes, it would find set the Position of the highest value associated with that Play and increment by one.

Where would I implement such logic within an EF code first model layer? And, in other cases, what if I wanted to massage data in code before it is checked for validation errors?

Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent to the Rails lifecycle hooks mentioned above, or some way to fake it at least. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override DbContext.SaveChanges, do the fix up there and call into base.SaveChanges(). If you do that you may want to call DetectChanges before doing the fix up. Btw. the very same issue is discussed in Programming Entity Framework DbContext book (ISBN 978-1-449-31296-1) on pages 192-194. And yes, this is in context of validation...

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `IValidatableObject`. That gives you a single hook:

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
```

And you can apply your validation logic there.

There's also a `SavingChanges` event on `ObjectContext` (which you can obtain from the `DbContext`).

You could just create a custom `IDoStuffOnSave` interface and apply it to your entities that need to execute some logic on save (there's nothing out of the box)

Comment: I would discourage changing entities from validation for several reasons: 1) if you happen to change a related entity that was not in the modified state before it won't be saved as DetectChanges is not called again after validation, 2) if you change a related entity that has already been validated in a way that makes it invalid you can get an exception during saving it to the database 3) this is a violation of single responsibility priniciple. For SavingChanges event - again this is after validation has happened so you can shoot yourself in the foot.